# What dimensions combinations are allowed in Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I set up my own customVarValue1 dimension in GA (which basically corresponds to a unique session), and am trying to generate reports via the API per this variable.

It works when my dimensions are `ga:customVarValue1,ga:channelGrouping`, but doesn't work when they are `ga:customVarValue1,ga:productSku` or `ga:customVarValue1,ga:userAgeBracket` (I get empty results).

What combinations of dimensions are allowed, and how can I get the ones that are not to work?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting empty results because there is no data.

[productSku](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_productsku)  is part of ecommerce which means it has hit type of transaction or item.   Most people when they add a custom var only add it for hit type pageview so unless you are 100% sure that you are also sending the custom dimension with your ecommerce hits then there wont be any data for a customdimension and a ecommerce value.

[userAgeBracket](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=audience&jump=ga_useragebracket) is tricky its one of the demographic and interest reports dimensions there may not be any relation between that and a custom dimension either.  But I think there should be.

You might want to try testing thought he [query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)